# Why the definition of Weil cohomology theory need the coefficients field to be of characteristic 0

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

A Weil cohomology is a functor from the category of smooth projective schemes over $k$ to the category of graded $K$-vector spaces which satisfies several axioms. In the definition, the characteristic of $K$ is also assumed to be 0, but why? To restate the question, why the positive characteristic cohomology theories are not 'reasonable'?

This question clearly are related to the following question,

[Coefficients of Weil Cohomology Theories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95448/coefficients-of-weil-cohomology-theories)

Comment: One of the original motivations was that you be able to count the number of points of variety over a finite field using the Lefschetz trace formula. If the cofficients were over a field of char $p$, you could, at best, count mod $p$.

Comment: Another reason is that characteristic $p$ cohomology theories pick up the $p$-torsion from the 'correct' cohomology. Serre in his Mexico paper (*Symposium internacional de topologia algebraica*) explains that he had earlier proposed the sum of the Hodge numbers as a good analogue of Betti numbers, but realised that they merely *dominate* the 'correct' numbers. This was later explained by torsion phenomena in Illusie's de Rham–Witt complex. The story is similar with algebraic de Rham cohomology and the torsion in crystalline cohomology.